# Trouble resetting connection string in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

New to Access 2010.  The following VBA code when run doesn't reset the connection string as expected.  I'm pretty sure this used to work.  What's wrong?

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("AccountNumber").Connect = "ODBC;Description=NativeClient;DRIVER=SQL Native Client;SERVER=server1;DATABASE=Expense;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
CurrentDb.TableDefs("AccountNumber").RefreshLink
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that connection string. Which version of SQL Server are you using? You might like to try a connection string from http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#p3, for example, this works for me.

```
scn = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
"Server=ServerName; Database=test;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
With CurrentDb
     .TableDefs(sLocalName).Connect = scn
     .TableDefs(sLocalName).RefreshLink
End with
```

Comment: It's sql 2005.  I will try this connection string.